# How to make GCC binaries in release mode?

Tags: debugging, gcc, release, configure, snapshot

While installing the latest `gcc7` from trunk with standard `./configure`, `make`, `make install` I found out that the gcc binaries (as was expected) are in debug mode (with debug information).

How can I configure and make it to be in release mode (i.e. make the binaries with `-O3`)? What is the corresponding option for `./configure`?

Comment: It isn't debug vs release. By default, you get -O2 -g, that is optimized but still with debug symbols. You can use make install-strip to remove the debug symbols. There is also make bootstrap-O3 to replace -O2 with -O3. This is all explained here: https://gcc.gnu.org/install/

Comment: More importantly if you got a gcc snapshot, you may want --enable-checking=release to disable expensive internal checking.